# overful \hbox . Someone could explain once for all?

Tags: boxes

I keep getting this error. I don't understand why, please someone could tell me where I'm doing wrong and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Sample code:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Si dice che un imposta è \textbf{progressiva} quando l'aliquota media dell'imposta aumenta all'aumentare del reddito complessivo. 
Dal punto di vista matematico l'aliquota media deve essere crescente, quindi:
$$\frac{\overline{t}(Y)}{dY} >0$$   \textit{Più sei ricco più, in media, paghi. Di conseguenza per verificare che l'imposta progressiva è sufficiente verificare che l'aliquota media di un soggetto ricco sia maggiore rispetto a quella di uno povero}.
\item Si dice che un'imposta è \textbf{costante} quando l'aliquota media 
\end{itemize}
```

Edit: Here's the document class and initial parameters. Please note I'm a noob.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It's no "error", it simply means that TeX hasn't been able to find a meaningful breaking point. However without the document class and the page size the code you are currently showing isn't enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I get this problem with a minimal setup so the main issue is that English hyphenation is being used, loading the Italian one solves the problem, but again you should post the exact code which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Hi, I posted the initail parametes. As you see it's already in italian.

Answer (score 9):

Compiling the code

```
\documentclass[draft]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% \usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Si dice che un imposta è \textbf{progressiva} quando l'aliquota media
dell'imposta aumenta all'aumentare del reddito complessivo. 
Dal punto di vista matematico l'aliquota media deve essere crescente, quindi:
$$\frac{\overline{t}(Y)}{dY} >0$$   \textit{Più sei ricco più, in media, paghi.
Di conseguenza per verificare che l'imposta progressiva è sufficiente verificare
che l'aliquota media di un soggetto ricco sia maggiore rispetto a quella di uno
povero}.
\item Si dice che un'imposta è \textbf{costante} quando l'aliquota media 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with the option `draft` shows where the overfull box is; this is useful in this case because the amount `0.11908pt` wouldn't be easy to spot.

Overfull boxes like this arise when TeX hasn't been able to find an adequate point to break the line. This is happening here because TeX does not know that you're writing Italian, so it's using the default English hyphenation patterns, as you see by the wrong hyphenation of *matematico*.

The line (commented out in the code above)

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
```

tells TeX to use the Italian hyphenation patterns, and you'll get a meaningful output

[image]

Side comments:
You shouldn't use `$$...$$` in LaTeX, please look at [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917). And "*un'imposta*" with apostrophe, please `;-)`

Comment: You explained me very well. Grazie :)